# JBoss7 setting Cache-Control, Pragma to no-cache for all responses from RESTEasy

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, jboss7.x, resteasy, cache-control

I'm trying to add Cache-Control headers to the responses generated in JBoss 7 using the RESTEasy framework. However, all the responses end up getting multiple Cache-Control headers due to JBoss adding a no-cache header by default.

I can't find any setting to remove it and adding interceptors is also not working since a no-cache header is being added later.

Can someone tell me how to disable the default pragma and cache-control headers in JBoss 7?

Note: I'm using resteasy with Stateless EJBs.

```
@Path("/api")
@Local
public interface UCSRestServiceInterface
{
    @GET
    @Path("/token")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Cache(maxAge = 3600, noTransform = true)
    public Response getToken();
}
```

Getting the response headers as,

```
{
  "pragma": "No-cache",
  "date": "Thu, 11 Feb 2016 20:16:30 GMT",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "cache-control": "no-cache, no-transform, max-age=3600",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "connection": "Keep-Alive",
  "keep-alive": "timeout=15, max=100",
  "expires": "Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST"
}
```

Comment: Write a filter. Take the response; and manipulate the headers you want.

Comment: I have the same issue with wildfly 10 (and it also seems to be like that in wildfly 8) where there is always also the following present in the reponse header: "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate". Adding the @Cache annotation just adds a second header field. This can't be correct behavior! Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A Filter resource in a web-app basically lets you intercept requests and response and mainly designed for some use cases which work by altering request/response headers. More details [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

Since you are using RESTEasy you can make use of ContainerResponseFilter; a filter interface provided by JAX-RS. You can write your custom filter by implementing this interface. The filter class(add one to your web app source code) will look like below:-

```
@Provider
public class YourCustomFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

// you can check the actual string value by using method "getStringHeaders" on 'resp' below
private static final String CACHE_CONTROL = "cache-control";

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req,
        ContainerResponseContext resp) throws IOException {

    if(resp.getHeaders().containsKey(CACHE_CONTROL)){
       resp.getHeaders().remove(CACHE_CONTROL);
       resp.getHeaders().add(CACHE_CONTROL, "no-transform, max-age=3600");
    }
    resp.getHeaders().add(CACHE_CONTROL, "no-transform, max-age=3600");

  }

}
```

Here you basically check for the prescense of Cache-Control header and if present remove the existing one and add one of your own.
Please dont forget the `@Provider` annotation which is needed by the jax rs runtime to discover your custom filter.

Note that with this filter all requests to your webapp will be intercepted. If you want a certain resource or a resource method to be intercepted you can explore the use of [@NameBinding](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-2/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html)

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sorry. But adding a filter is also not solving the problem. The only header found by the filter is content-type which indicates JBOSS is adding the Pragma + Cache-Control header after the response filter is processed.

Comment: Looks like there is a solution at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/28847 but I don't have paid subscription to view it.

Comment: Sorry. Was away from SO for couple of days. You can try two things:-  1) Try Adding @BindingPriority(0) annotation to your Filter.    2) Navigate to your server.xml  found in <JBOSSDIR/ deploy/jboss-web/server.xml and check for any cache setting set on a valve tag and change that .

Comment: Don't see any BindingPriority annotation in  resteasy. There is no valve setting in standalone.xml in jboss 7 (server.xml is in older versions).

Comment: Tried @Priority but still didn't help. The issue appears to be non jax-rs or resteasy related.

Comment: @Gary, thank you, I had the same error with JBoss. I found this on that link:
"The Pragma and Cache-Control headers are automatically inserted in the response when the web application is secured with a <security-constraint>."

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround consisting in setting empty value for Pragma header when "Cache-Control" header is present and "no-cache" is absent

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.CacheControl;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR - 1)
@Provider
public class PragmaRemover implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static final String PRAGMA = "Pragma";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
        if(headers.containsKey(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL)){
            for (Object header : headers.get(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL)) {
                CacheControl cacheControl = (CacheControl) header;
                if(!cacheControl.isNoCache()){
                    headers.add(PRAGMA, "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR - 1` is to be sure that the cache header has been set by resteasy.

And don't forget to add this filter to your Jax-Rs application.