# Response being cached by AWS Api Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using the below class to make rest calls. I am making a get call to one of the apis that is exposed. The api returns either true or false. Whem I use `invocation.get()` the response seems to be cached. Is it the expected behavior when using this class/method. If so , how can I get around this?

```
javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;

Invocation.Builder invocation = target.request(acceptType);
final CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
cacheControl.setNoCache(true);
cacheControl.setMaxAge(1);
cacheControl.setMustRevalidate(true);
cacheControl.setNoStore(true);
invocation.cacheControl(cacheControl);
```

Comment: For [Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934316/jersey-default-cache-control-to-no-cache) for [rest easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097400/jboss7-setting-cache-control-pragma-to-no-cache-for-all-responses-from-resteasy)

Comment: @VictorGubin In my case the api is python code running in AWS lambda behind AWS API Gateway. When I see a stale response in my client , I don't see a request coming to lambda. So in order to check if api gateway is returning cached response , I tried running the same request multiple times using postman. However I always see the correct response. So I believe the rest client which I had pasted above is somehow caching stale response and returning it occasionally. I believe the links provide ways for ensuring cached data is not being returned from server and doesn't address client side caching

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Check [this](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter11/caching.html), caching depends on HTTP request/response headers. Postman uses their own transport (chromium engine), when your JAX-RS provider uses their own, in any case it should depend on HTTP headers (from both client and server sides).

Comment: I added the cache control header as specified in my updated post. But it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: I am able to replicate the issue when I use curl as well . I used postman console and passed all the headers passed by postman in curl but I still get a stale response.

Comment: Do you have caching turned on in your API Gateway config? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html

Comment: Apologies , this turned out to be a really stupid error on my part , sorry for wasting your time. I had deployed lambda in both east and west and I had updated the config only in east. I figured out the issue when I looked closely into our splunk logs. @VictorGubin and bwest - Thanks for your help!!